# Caliburn Micro and sharing view models across apps

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, windows-phone, caliburn.micro, mvvmcross

I am looking into potentially using Caliburn Micro for an upcoming Windows Phone and Windows RT application and I'm wondering if it's possible, or advisable, to reuse view models across both platforms?

I have seen examples using Portable Libraries and in another framework called MvvmCross, but I'm not sure if I could do this using Caliburn because I can't add Caliburn to a Portable Library and therefore can't share interfaces, such as INavigationService, with view models sitting in the shared portable library.

I am thinking of simply having one set of view models for Windows Phone and another for WinRT.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an experiment I took parts of CM and made it portable so my view models could live in a portable.  I mainly wanted to take advantage of screens and conductors in a portable and only have one set of view models.

The creator of CM has mentioned making CM 2.0 support portables but it will be a decent amount of work.

I've experimented with MvvmCross and the [v3](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross) stuff is really slick even if you're not targeting iOS or Android.

So, for CM, the only option with the current version is to have separate view models for WinRT and WP.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I had a feeling that would be the way to go. Without wanting to go off topic too much would you lean more towards MVX or CM for a WP/RT app?

Comment: Right now I'm leaning towards Mvx simply because my view models can live in a portable.